# Azure DevOps GIT Release Pipeline : Import ARM JSON : Agent Pool not loading

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are importing Azure DevOps GIT Release Pipelines from ARM JSONs. However, every time when we import the JSON, the "Agent Pool" setting in the Release Pipeline shows up as blank!

[image: Agent Pool Setting blank after import]

We have to manually fix this setting each and every time as follows:

[image: AgentPoolSettingManuallySet]

The relevant code in the ARM JSON is as follows:

```
..,
"deployPhases" : [
  { "deploymentInput" : {
      "parallelExecution" : { "parallelExecutionType" : "none" },
      "agentSpecification" : null,
      "skipArtifactsDownload" : false,
      "artifactsDownloadInput" : {},
      "queueId" : 456,
      "demands" : [],
      "enableAccessToken" : false,
      "timeoutInMinutes" : 0,
      "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes" : 1,
      "condition" : "succeeded()",
      "overrideInputs" : {}
    },
    "rank"          : 1,
    "phaseType"     : "agentBasedDeployment",
    "name"          : "DEV Agent Job",
    "refName"       : null,
    "workflowTasks" : [..]
  }
], ..
```

Has anyone else also faced this issue? Were you able to solve it, such that immediately after importing the Release Pipeline ARM JSON, then the Agent Pool setting is set correctly. That is, without manual intervention?

***Notes :***

- I've even tried to set "agentSpecification" to `{ "identifier" : "windows-2019" }` .. to no avail
- when I fire the below, I get results as shown further on. That is, I see the PoolID = 456 in this case, which is also what I've set above as the "queueId". I've even tried with 123 .. but that does not work either:

`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/distributedtask/queues`

```
{ "count" : ..,
  "value" : [
    { "id":123,"projectId":"xxx","name":"Azure Pipelines",
      "pool":{"id":456,"scope":"yyy","name":"Azure Pipelines","isHosted":true,"poolType":"automation","size":17,"isLegacy":false,"options":"none"}
    },
    ..
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design in Azure Pipeline. The export/import is a best effort. After performing the import, you are dropped into the build designer where any input that needs your attention is outlined in red.

When it comes to some resources, like the Agent Pool, the export/import doesn’t assume that the resource is available or that you have access to it. So you must select it again yourself.

The common export/import scenario would mean you are moving to another project, or perhaps another collection/organization. In the project case, the project may not have access to that same Agent Pool. In the organization case, the Agent Pool would be a different entity.